# Extract id values within quotation marks "" in R

Tags: regex, xml, r

I have the following data (XML/OSM file extract):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<osm version="0.6" generator="Osmosis 0.44.1">
  <node id="3569633" version="1" timestamp="2016-03-02T22:09:35Z">
    <tag k="housenumber" v="8"/>
    <tag k="street" v="Test Street"/>
  </node>
  <relation id="3571336" version="1" timestamp="2016-03-02T22:09:35Z">
    <member type="way" ref="3571337" role="outer"/>
    <tag k="type" v="boundary"/>
    <tag k="admin_level" v="8"/>
    <tag k="boundary" v="administrative"/>
  </relation>
 <way id="3536236" version="1" timestamp="2016-03-02T22:09:35Z">
    <nd ref="3536237"/>
    <nd ref="3536238"/>
    <nd ref="3536239"/>
    <nd ref="3536240"/>
    <nd ref="3536241"/>
 </way>
</osm>
```

What i now want to do is extract the id numbers so in this case:

```
3569633
3571336
3536236
```

and save it as a vector so that i can use the max() function on it.

Im open to any ("fast") R solution. I tried using the xml package but was unsuccessful because my Xpath knowledge is to basic. I also thought of using regex but here ,too, i miss the knowledge.
When using an Text Editor capable of applying regex expressions i came quite far with the following expression:

```
id="(\d+)"
```

but that would mark all the:

```
id="3569633"
```

part. If i could adjust that to just find the values between the quotation marks. I could use the `readLines()` function and perhaps `grep()`

Any Help would be appreciated.

Bonus would be to extract also the numbers of the `ref=""` part so that the final vector would contain the following values:

```
3569633
3571336
3536236
3536237
3536238
3536239
3536240
3536241
```

Comment: You can easily get the `ref` attribute values with `//*/@ref`,  `id` with `//*/@id`. Please post the XML code you tried.

Comment: With [this](https://regex101.com/r/wB5yK2/2) you can select the group with  `$2`. With [this](https://regex101.com/r/wB5yK2/3) you can use positive lookbehind.

Answer (score 0):

Though I **discourage** using regex for parsing XML and HTML stuff.

For this particular case you will only have to use `look around` assertions like this.

**Regex:** `(?<=id="|ref=")\d+(?=")`

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=id="|ref=")` Will lookbehind for `id` OR `ref` part.
- `\d+` will match your number. And `(?=")` will lookahead for closing quotes.

### <kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xW9xU6/1)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get what you need with `XML` package using a very basic XPath:

```
> library(XML)
> url = "PATH_TO_XML_FILE"
> parsed_doc = htmlParse(file=url, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
> attrs <- getNodeSet(doc = parsed_doc, path = "//*[@id or @ref]")
> ids <- sapply(attrs, xmlGetAttr, "id") 
> refs <- sapply(attrs, xmlGetAttr, "ref")
> res <- mapply(c, ids, refs, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
> unlist(res)
[1] "3569633" "3571336" "3571337" "3536236" "3536237" "3536238" "3536239" "3536240" "3536241"
```

The `//*[@id or @ref]` XPath expression will fetch all nodes that have `id` and `ref` attributes. With `sapply(attrs, xmlGetAttr, "id")`, you will get the values of the `id` attributes. In a similar way, you can get the `ref` attribute values and append them to the existing list of `id` attributes and then you can merge the two lists with `mapply(c, ids, refs, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want nd @refs, try

```
doc <- xmlParse('your XML above')
#xpathSApply(doc, "//@id|//@ref")
 xpathSApply(doc, "//@id|//nd/@ref")
       id        id        id       ref       ref       ref       ref       ref 
"3569633" "3571336" "3536236" "3536237" "3536238" "3536239" "3536240" "3536241"
```